# ASP.Net MySql select error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I run this function on my asp.net website:

```
private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string strConnString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=database;UID=root;PASSWORD=123456789;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this query:

```
"select * from Client where id='"+ customerId +"'"
```

And i get this Exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Any idea what can fix this?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using a program like MySQLWorkbench or HeidiSQL? If so, does the query (when `customerId` is replaced with actual data) execute correctly?

Comment: SqlConnection is used to connect o MS SQL Server, not to mysql

Comment: @IlyaBursov you could write the answer then....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253120/asp-net-use-sqlconnection-connect-mysql

Comment: Is the asp.net code running on the same machine as the SQL Server (localhost)?

Comment: Are you connecting to mysql or mssql? please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting with Mysql, try this:

*Add Mysql.Data.dll, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net)

*Add this line on top of your page

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

And try this edited method:

```
private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string strConnString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=database;UID=root;PASSWORD=123456789;";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```