# Why SQL Server connection error when I'm using MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

`web.config`

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebFront" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=webfront;Uid=devadmin;Pwd=*******" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

...  

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Everything connects fine from my unit tests. Could this be that I'm not providing any other authentication than what is in the connection string? Is there something else in the site that I'm missing? Not using Owin, Identity or anything. Just trying to learn some basic stuff before I add on all the bells and whistles.

Comment: This simply means that your machine is unable to connet to the server.

Comment: Please verify that your machine is able to access the server on which DB is present.

Comment: Its on the same machine ... running localhost, local IIS express, all from VS2015.

Comment: Change from locahost to 127.0.0.1 or the IP of your machine.

Comment: Changing to 127.0.0.1 did not help. I wouldn't need to specify port 3306 (I think that is default) would I? Tried the actual IP address but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

since the unit tests work and you get the error in your main application/site, and I assume you ran the unit testing in your visual studio and the main application from the IIS server - that's the source of your problem, one of the configurations in the iis is not correct, make sure you have the right authentication method, and that the application pool is configured correctly

Comment: How do you configure IIS when it is being run from Visual Studio?

Answer (score -2):

SqlConnection is for SqlServer. To connect to MySql you need to download some [drivers](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html) and reference it in your project, and use MySqlConnection instead.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253120/asp-net-use-sqlconnection-connect-mysql) and this [CodeProject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp).

Comment: See the `web.config` ... all the references are made.