# How to verify that you are connected to a MySQL database in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I added the reference for the MySQL server in C#.  I thought I have this code right.  I know the connection values are right for testing.  Here is my error:

{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

My WPF text boxes and Buttons:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textError" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="125,39,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="If Error this will show it" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textUser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="125,118,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="125,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

My C# code:

```
namespace namespace1
{
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textUser.Text != "" & textPassword.Text != "")
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "test";
            uid = "username";
            password = "password";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            string queryText = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 
                         WHERE username = @Username AND password = @Password";

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textUser.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textPassword.Text);
                int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Logged In!");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("User Not Found!");
            }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not ever store passwords as plain text.  Hash and salt them.

Comment: send off an interesting query, like `select 7 as seven`  ... see what you get back.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure it worked then add encryption later....  I was wanting to do Blowfish but haven't seen any code online for C# to do that.  Only the outdated MD5.

Comment: So It may be a problem with my query then... I will check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the MySQL download page entitled [Download Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) and proceed with the obvious. Note seek out the most recent download as this will age.

Use the appropriate **MySQL classes**.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string connString = @"server=localhost;userid=drew;password=OpenSesame;database=stackoverflow";
```

.

```
        long lRet = 0;
        using (MySqlConnection lconn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            lconn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = lconn;
                cmd.CommandText = @"select count(*) as theCount from batchQMetricsToUpdate where status=1";
                lRet = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        return(lRet);
```

Add References screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Note that I did not see your `cn` in your using block for the cmd as the 2nd parameter in the constructor. So sorry if the first part of my answer was way off base. Good luck.

Comment: I did try this, just to make sure, but unfortunately it did not go.  Most of the time it usually is something simple, but it has to drive you nuts first! :)

Comment: I was debugging it and it wasn't liking this command  = ExecuteScalar.  Wasn't sure how to get around that

Comment: I tried the MySqlConnection instead of SqlConnection, but it says it cannot convert it... how funky is that!

Comment: I don't know what classes you are using, but it appears not to be the ones for MySQL. I have been wrong before.

Comment: MySQL.Data.Dll  I tried it on a basic connection to the server and it worked with this one from MySQL.  So I know it is trying, just something in my syntax

Comment: I think I have said it many different ways. Let this guy say it for you :p ..... http://stackoverflow.com/a/18253163

Comment: Your `using` block is using the wrong connection class datatype.

Comment: You are right, MS SQL vs MySQL - Now I have to figure out how to convert it. Which I am trying your methods! :)

Comment: Hardcode your connection string exactly like mine (not your format). Do a silly `select 7 as seven` as a test like I showed you. It is nearly fool proof.

Comment: I am guessing with the return I should make this a private method, because being a button it is naturally void.

Comment: Well feel free to join me in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat room anytime. I can show screen shots of n-tier development to get these objects to talk to one another and nestle the data where it needs to be. `n-tier` meaning you want separation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        switch(ex.Number) 
        { 
            case 18456: // Can't login
                // Do something
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

To get the complete list of codes run:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: It says it's a connection error though....  I tried your code, and had to edit the conn.open().  It is a formatting issue of some sort.

Comment: using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn))  I think it comes from doing both these commands