# Connecting MySQL database with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I made a MySQL server database file from server explorer using the following code to connect the MySQL database:

```
private void DataAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString =
             "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
             "User Instance=true;" +
             "Integrated Security=false;" +
             "AttachDbFilename=C:\\Path\\filename.MDF;";
          conn.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Connected to database");
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
    }
}
```

But the connection always fails.

The error that I found while debugging:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll       ("The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.")

Comment: You must use MySqlConnection for MySql. You cannot use SqlConnection, because that is for Sql Server.

Comment: Sorry.. corrected the format.. kindly recheck

Comment: and the connectionstring is for sql server local db, and not for mysql. The proper mysql connection string is here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I am selecting "Microsoft SQL server database file" from Server Explorer, Is that correct for mysql connection strings?

Comment: No, it is wrong. SQL Server and MySql is 2 different database. Read that connection string again : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to MySQL, you need MySqlConnection and a proper MySQL connection string:

```
private void DataAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var conn = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.1.10;Database=myDB;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;");
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected to database");
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use MySQLConnection as answered here:

*[ASP.NET use SqlConnection connect MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253120/asp-net-use-sqlconnection-connect-mysql/18253163#18253163)*

The MySQL connection library might not be included in your solution, so you will need to download it. And change `var conn = new SqlConnection();` to:

```
var conn = new MySqlConnection();
```