# C# SqlConnection stop at method: Open()

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlconnection

```
        String connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1:3306;Database=joonggonara;Uid=root;Pwd=apmsetup;";
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;

        int a = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

I execute in debug mode.

[image: Error]

I got an error

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My SQL server version is 5.1.41-community MySQL Community Server
I want to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET use SqlConnection connect MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253120/asp-net-use-sqlconnection-connect-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `SqlConnection` class to connect to MySQL Server; it can only connect to Microsoft SQL Server.

Instead, install [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data) or [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector) and use the `MySqlConnection` class.

Additionally, you can't combine the host IP and port into one connection string option. Since the default port for MySQL is `3306`, change your connection string to `"server=127.0.0.1;Database=joonggonara;Uid=root;Pwd=apmsetup"`.

Comment: @윤정도 if this helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers