# How to fix "Keyword not supported: 'port'." in C# using DataSets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, dataset

i'm new in C# and i want to generate crystal report in C# but it shows an error message "Keyword not supported: 'port'.".
The error is occured at  `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sme_erpConnectionString);` For the database, im using MariaDb
Please anyone know how to fix this? I already search in the internet but still got error. Thank you.

Here is my CrystalReportDemoController

```
public class CrystalReportDemoController : Controller
    {

        protected static string erpConnectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["erpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        // GET: CrystalReportDemo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult downloadReport()
        {
            var _data = new List<EmpData>();
            CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();
            SqlDataReader dr = ExeQuery("table_customer");
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var x = new EmpData()
                    {
                        id = int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString()),
                        item_master_cd = dr["item_master_cd"].ToString(),
                    };
                    _data.Add(x);
                }
            }
            cr.SetDataSource(_data);
            Class1.PassData = cr;
            return Redirect("~/Report/ReportCrystal.aspx");
        }
        private SqlDataReader ExeQuery(string str)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(erpConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 50000;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
            return dr;
        }
        public class EmpData
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string item_master_cd { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="erpConnectionString" connectionString="server=xx.x.xx.xx;user id=mydb;password=mydb123;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3306;database=erpdatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET use SqlConnection connect MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253120/asp-net-use-sqlconnection-connect-mysql)

Comment: hi, i'm changing SQLConnection to MySQLConnection based on your suggestion, but the 'conn" in "using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn))" got error message. it says that Argument2: cannot convert from MysqlConnector.MySqlConnection to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection. For the database im using mariadb

Comment: You have to change `Sql` to `MySql` *everywhere*.